# How to create JSON from a dictionary in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

Edit: I have read the other answers on SO for the same issue , however Im unable to get the desired output. I have tried many variations as suggested in other questions but its not working.

I have a JSON snipped which needs to be added as the body when I open a websocket.

```
sender: "system1@example.com",
recipients:"system2@example.com",
data: {
    text: "Test Message"
},
```

So using Swift I did the following,

```
var messageDictionary : [String: Any] = [
    "sender": "system1@example.com",
    "recipients":"system2@example.com",
    "data": [
        "text": "Test Message"
    ],
]
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: messageDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
    socket.write(string: jsonString!)
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

When I print the jsonString, I get

```
Optional("{\n  \"sender\" : \"system1@example.com\",\n  \"data\" : {\n    
    \"text\" : \"Test Message\"\n  },\n  \"recipients\" : 
    \"system2@example.com\"\n}")
```

as the console output. I expected the above snippet to be formatted as JSON.
How to get the output as normal JSON without the /n and additional spaces?
Im using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.1

**Edit 2**:

let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: messageDictionary, options: [])
let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])

I tried doing the above and I get the following as the output:

```
{
    data =     {
        text = Test Message;
    };
    recipients = "system1@example.com";
    sender = "system2@example.com";
}
```

However the websocket expects this:

```
{ "sender":"system1@example.com","recipients":
["system2@example.com"],"data":{"text":"Test Message"}}
```

Even with a slight variation like misplacing of double quotes the websocket server doesnt accept the input. How to exactly format the JSOn this way so that the websocket can accept it?

Comment: What you are asking is unnecessary thing , Actually Dictionary itself a JSON , You can directly pass `Data`  object , if you pass that thing as a string then only you need to convert Data to String

Comment: Unrelated but are you really sure you want ASCII encoding and not UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, it should be UTF-8. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @JonSnow The issue is the websocket I'm pinging, expects the data in certain format as I have mentioned above. Any variation and the socket doesnt consider the input.

Comment: "How to get the output as normal JSON without the /n and additional spaces?" ... Don't use the `.prettyPrinted` option, which is what is inserting the `\n` and additional spaces. That having been said, JSON web service doesn't care if the newline and spaces are there. It's just looking weird because the JSON was an optional and you didn't unwrap it. If you unwrap it and print it, it will look fine and can be used by web service as it is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After trying out various ways, the below way is what worked for me for getting the exact format required by the backend.

```
var messageDictionary = [
    "sender":"system1@example.com",
    "recipients":[
        "system2@example.com"
    ],
    "data":[
        "text" : data
    ]
] as [String : Any]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: messageDictionary)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can just cast to String

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: .prettyPrinted)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now JSONEncoder can do the work easily.

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let data = try encoder.encode(yourDictionary)

print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```