# Is there any way to encode the dictionary into JSON form using JSONEncoder

Tags: ios, swift

Here the Dictionary

```
struct Person : Codable {
    let name : String?
    let city : String?
    let age : Int?
}

let dic : [String : Any] = 
    ["name":"Manna","city" : "Rangpur", "age": 18,
     "name":"Munna","city" :"Dhaka","age":19,
     "name":"Shaon","city" :"Rangpur","age":11,
     "name":"Limon","city" :"Tangail","age":15,
     "name":"Lalon","city" :"Rangpur","age":18,
     "name":"Rakib","city" :"Dhaka","age":15, 
     "name":"Mum","city" :"Rangpur","age":18,
     "name":"Man","city" :"Bogura","age":12,
     "name":"Limon","city" :"Tangail","age":18]


// let manna = Person(name: "Manna", city: "Rangpur", age: 18)
// Here i want to use the dictionary

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    do {
         let data  = try encoder.encode(manna)
         print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    } catch {
        print("error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

trying to encode this dictionary just like json file as an output using JSONEncoder

Comment: What you are expecting as output? array of object?

Comment: just like JSON format {
  "name" : "Manna",
  "city" : "Rangpur",
  "age" : 18
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create JSON from a dictionary in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524218/how-to-create-json-from-a-dictionary-in-swift-4)

Comment: @MannaICT13 - please try a little searching before posting a question.

Comment: Do you need dictionary from array of `Person` object? I mean `[Person]` to `[[String: Any]]`? or reverse?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your dictionary is wrong because dictionary doesn't contains same key.

You can present it as like array of dictionary

```
let dic : [[String : Any]] = [["name":"Manna", "city" : "Rangpur", "age": 18],
                            ["name":"Munna","city" :"Dhaka","age":19,],
                            ["name":"Shaon","city" :"Rangpur","age":11,],
                            ["name":"Limon","city" :"Tangail","age":15,],
                            ["name":"Lalon","city" :"Rangpur","age":18,],
                            ["name":"Rakib","city" :"Dhaka","age":15,],
                            ["name":"Mum","city" :"Rangpur","age":18,],
                            ["name":"Man","city" :"Bogura","age":12,],
                            ["name":"Limon","city" :"Tangail","age":18]]
```

Now you can convert this array of dictionary into JSON as like below

```
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
    print(data.count)
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(json ?? "")
}
```