# How do i create and sent a JSON to the server using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I want to sent a JSON to the server,with details of user and options selected by the user. Currently i just save those in simple arrays.

I want to create a JSON and sent it to the server. Normally i can just add each those fields on Parameter with Alamofire. But here i have an issue is that, the number of fields depend on the number of users(or passenger count).

I haven't done this type before and i am a newbie into iOS developing.

```
{
    "contactPerson": {
        "email": {
            "email": "memine@gmail.com",
            "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
            "preferred": false,
            "shareMarketInd": false
        },
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "Me",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "Mine"
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
            "countryCode": "93",
            "markedForSendingRezInfo": false,
            "preferred": false,
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "subscriberNumber": "123456789"
        },
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "useForInvoicing": false
    },
    "curr": "USD",
    "flight1": "{fligh1Info}",
        "flight2": "{flight2Info}",
    "passengers": [{
        "accompaniedByInfant": true,
        "birthDate": {
            "day": 6,
            "fractionalSecond": 0.000,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "month": 9,
            "orig_day": 6,
            "orig_fracSeconds": 0.000,
            "orig_hour": 0,
            "orig_minute": 0,
            "orig_month": 9,
            "orig_second": 0,
            "orig_timezone": 330,
            "orig_year": 1991,
            "second": 0,
            "timezone": 330,
            "year": 1991
        },
        "hasStrecher": false,
        "parentSequence": 0,
        "passengerTypeCode": "ADLT",
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "some",
            "nameTitle": "Mr.",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "guy"
        },
        "requestedSeatCount": 1,
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "unaccompaniedMinor": false
    }, {
        "accompaniedByInfant": false,
        "birthDate": {
            "day": 10,
            "fractionalSecond": 0.000,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "month": 10,
            "orig_day": 10,
            "orig_fracSeconds": 0.000,
            "orig_hour": 0,
            "orig_minute": 0,
            "orig_month": 10,
            "orig_second": 0,
            "orig_timezone": 330,
            "orig_year": 2010,
            "second": 0,
            "timezone": 330,
            "year": 2010
        },
        "hasStrecher": false,
        "parentSequence": 0,
        "passengerTypeCode": "CHLD",
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "some",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "child"
        },
        "requestedSeatCount": 1,
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "unaccompaniedMinor": false
    }, {
        "accompaniedByInfant": false,
        "birthDate": {
            "day": 1,
            "fractionalSecond": 0.000,
            "hour": 0,
            "minute": 0,
            "month": 1,
            "orig_day": 1,
            "orig_fracSeconds": 0.000,
            "orig_hour": 0,
            "orig_minute": 0,
            "orig_month": 1,
            "orig_second": 0,
            "orig_timezone": 330,
            "orig_year": 2018,
            "second": 0,
            "timezone": 330,
            "year": 2018
        },
        "hasStrecher": false,
        "parentSequence": 0,
        "passengerTypeCode": "INFT",
        "personName": {
            "givenName": "some",
            "shareMarketInd": false,
            "surname": "kid"
        },
        "requestedSeatCount": 1,
        "shareMarketInd": false,
        "unaccompaniedMinor": false
    }],
    "pwd": "password",
    "requestPurpose": "MODIFY_PERMANENTLY_AND_CALC",
    "unm": "username"
}
```

This is my JSON. Here number of `flight1` `flight2` .... depends on number of flights picked by the user.

and number of objects inside `passengers` depends on number of passengers selected by the user.

How do i do this part?

Comment: you need to create `NSDictionary` that contain above structure and convert it to json. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524218/how-to-create-json-from-a-dictionary-in-swift-4)

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Ok but how do i add the number of flights and number of passengers to that exact place in the NSDictionary? (as both of those changes depending on user selection)

Comment: @PratikPrajapati You don't need `NSDictionary`, you need Swift Dictionary (`[String:Any]`)

Comment: create array that hold value like `[ "flight1": "{fligh1Info}", "flight2": "{fligh2Info}"]` and add/remove this value on user selection, after add this data to your main `Dictionary`.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Oh thank you. One question, if i just move it to array like that, how will i know that this part is added to the correct place in the json?(or the dictionary)?

Comment: In Dictionary place doesn't matter, whether your data `flight1` added at top of Dictionary or end of Dictionary. What matter is `flight1` key is exist in your Dictionary with your data.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati will the server accept if the position of flight1 is different from the json i posted on my question?

Comment: yes it will, just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a dictionary of [String: Any] type like below example.

```
let param : [String: Any] = ["contactPerson": [ "email":[ "email": "text@mail.com"], "markedForSendingRezInfo": false], "personName": [], "curr": "USD", "flight1" : [], "flight2" : [] ]
```

You can add key value in param as per request parameter requirement. then pass this param to alamofire request param.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your data in Dictionary

> Swift5

```
let dictData = ["name": "vicky", "phoneNumber": "01234567"]
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(dictData) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
        }
    }
```